# Driver doesn't start due to a digital signature related error

Tags: driver, digital-signature

I developed a driver an with `makecert`, `certmgr` and `signtool`. I created a digital signature (for Win 7 64 bit) and sign it to the driver (`.sys`-File). In the settings of the sys-file I see that he has the digital-File which is also value.

In the mmc->certificates I see the creates signature under trusted certificates.
When I start the driver with `sc start` then come the error 577 that the digital signature cannot be checked.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I created the signature with the following command line statements:

```
makecert.exe -$ individual -r -pe -ss "my Certificates" -n CN="certmaker" "myfirstcert.cer" 
certmgr.exe /add "myfirstcert.cer" /s /r localMachine root
SignTool.exe sign /v /s "my Certificates" /n "certmaker" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "C:\Windows\System32\driversMyFirstDriver.sys"
```

Comment: Why do you rely on us to correctly format your question? Your title doesn't start capitalized and isn't clear, you misspelled some words. Why not at least spell check your question?